# Can we Create Product Attributes Programmatically without using setup Script in magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-attribute, programmatically, magento2.3.4

Can you help to Create Product Attributes Programmatically without using setup Script in magento 2.3 ?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? as if you want to create a product attribute programatically you should create a module with such a file


Setup/Patch/Data/AddMytestattributeProductAttribute.php

Comment: Usually we will create setup script for Product attribute creation, this will execute when we run php bin/magento setup:upgrade command. If we want to add another attribute again we need to create setup upgrade and follow the same process. Here my requirement is frequently I will get product attributes for different brands as a CSV. So, If I create any module which will create product attributes when ever I run some url (Ex : domain.com/frontname/attribue/createAttribute) it should take the CSV values and create attribute as per given type (text, dropdown, yes/no etc..)

Comment: Can we create a module to fulfill my requirement ?

Comment: means you just need an import module for product attributes. There are already several modules that could be useful for you. Dependent on where your attributes are stored outside of Magento, maybe also a module specifically for imports from your pim to magento

Comment: @shankarboss Yes it is possible to create a separate module for that. All you have to do is create a **controller** which takes all the required classes needed for creation of product attributes and the **execution** method should be responsible for creation of the the product attributes.